# Unable to launch Topcoder IcedTea Arena in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, oracle, android-studio

I was able to start the arena last week. I had jdk version 7 in my system. Yesterday, I installed oracle java version 8 to install Android Studio. From then on, I am unable to launch topcoder arena. Is it due to the oracle java? Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in the directory where the applet is stored-

```
javaws <name_of_applet>
```

Comment: U mean javaws Topcoder? I wrote it and I got "unable to launch application error"

Comment: No, I mean the filename of the applet. It is generally ContestAppletProd.jnlp . Did you type it into the terminal after `cd` -ing into the folder?

Answer (score 1):

For TopCoder (and this may work for other sites too), for the current version of Java from Oracle (Java 8 update 91 while posting), you may NOT be able to launch the arena by simply running the command `javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp` because of some newly added security restrictions in Java. In order to be able to launch TopCoder arena, I had to perform the following -

1. Open `Java Control Panel` by running command `javaws -viewer` on terminal.
2. On the `Security` tab, set the desired security level to `High` to have somewhat permissive behavior.
3. Add TopCoder to the `Exception Site List` in the same tab. For me, adding the [TopCoder](https://www.topcoder.com/) URL alone didn't suffice. I had to add the HTTP URL (http://www.topcoder.com) to the list as well to be able to launch the arena.
4. Apply these changes to `Java Control Panel` and relaunch the arena by running the command `javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp`.

Hope this helps!